# i m having 10 images are in galary.so,how to make an animate the image one by one in android?

Tags: android, image, animation

I have 10 images and they are in a gallery. How can I animate the images one by one on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use AnimationListener class. 
this class contains the methods like onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) and onAnimationStart(Animation animation)
maybe that would help.

[here is the link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html)